# Why can I inherit from a generic type at runtime, but not compile time?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, reflection.emit

So I was doing some experimenting, and I found that while this:

```
public class SelfOfT
{
    // This won't compile
    public class FailureOf<T> : T
    {

    }
}
```

fails, this, on the other hand:

```
public class SelfOfT
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {

    }

    public static void Second()
    {
        // This works fine, and achieves the same end as what I'm trying to do with FailureOf<T>
        AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("Dynamics");
        AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder modbuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
        TypeBuilder typeBuild = modbuilder.DefineType("SuccessfulOf", TypeAttributes.Public);

        typeBuild.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IMyInterface));
        var TParam = typeBuild.DefineGenericParameters(new String[] { "T" }).First();
        TParam.SetGenericParameterAttributes(GenericParameterAttributes.None);

        Type myType = typeBuild.CreateType();
        Type genericMyType = myType.MakeGenericType(typeof(IMyInterface));

        IMyInterface my = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(genericMyType);

    }
}
```

works fine. It seems like it would save a lot of trouble to just make this available at compile time if I can do it at runtime anyway.

Comment: Where in your second snippet do you declare that `SuccessfulOf<T>` extends `T`?

Comment: Based on the answers I see that because I know what `<T>` is supposed to be I can get away with what I'm doing. But I guess the question is why can I implement `IEnumerable<T>` if I can't do `<T>` by itself? In both situations, `T` is unknown.

Comment: @sircodesalot, with `: IEnumerable<T>`, you are simply passing that type argument along.  That is a very different idea than subclassing from an arbitrary type, or implementing one too, for that matter.  That's why you can't have `class C<T> : object, T`.  It would be interesting if the language allowed that kind of expressiveness, but C# doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Uhm, you're not allowed to do that at runtime either.

Note that in your case, you're **not** specifying the class to inherit from.

To do that, you need to use one of the overloads to [DefineType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.definetype.aspx) that takes a `Type` parameter to inherit from.

However, at runtime, you're not allowed to specify `T` either for that parameter, you would have to specify a *specific* type, which would be no difference from compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Your code that uses reflection actually defines this:

```
public class SuccessfulOf<T> : IMyInterface
{

}
```

You cannot do what you want (`class FailureOf<T> : T`) because the base type `T` must be known at compile-time. At run-time with reflection you can still not do it, since `T` must be known.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second code you are declaring the type `public class FailureOf<T> : IMyInterface`, not `public class FailureOf<T> : T`.

Even if you declare the generic type in the surrounding class, you still can't inherit from it because you can't inherit a type parameter.